# How to filter firebase data results by applying multiple Query in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: My database Structure is as follows]

I want to display all the worker names whose city="Varanasi" and gender="Male" and salary is between 5000 to 15000 in a Recycler View.
In this case the name of the shown worker must be displayed.
What query must be applied and how should it be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query based on multiple where clauses in firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think you need save the salary with double value, not string.

You need your reference at worker node, then add a listener and iterate the values. Also you need a worker class to obtain the data.

```
yourReference.orderByChild("city").equalTo("Varanasi").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(){

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(Datasnapshot data){
       for(Datasnapshot d: data.getChildren()){
         yourClass work = d.getValue(yourClass.class);
         if(work.getGender().equals("Male"){
            double salary = work.getSalary();
           if(salary  > 5000 && salary < 15000){
                 //save the worker into a list. 
            }
         } 
       }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a safe approach to fetch all the data but to show only relevant ones?

Answer (score 1):

Acording to this tutorial, [The Firebase Database For SQL Developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) you can create a new field for each node named: `city_gender`. For you particular example the value of this field will be `Varanasi_Male`. This how it should look like:

> city_gender: "Varanasi_Male"

In this way, you can query your Firebase database for every worker who is a `male` and works in `Varanasi`. In the same way you can achieve this for intervals.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just watched some of the videos from the series, and that looked like a total hack! As of now, do you know if functions were added to allow multi-filtering without having to manually modify the noSQL logic?

Comment: @RedM I'm not sure I understand your question, but please post a new one using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.