# Filtering Firebase data in adapter leaves empty space

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I need to filter childs of a Firebase Database upon an (int) Type that must be equal to 1, 2 and 6.
It is not possible to do it with NoSQL filtering of Firebase

So I will take all the records and tell the adapter to not all of display them

my code is based on the database example of Firebase and modify inherited class

```
public class AllPostsFragment extends PostListFragment {
```

this methode will take all the records (Posts)

```
    @Override
public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

    Query AllPostsQuery = databaseReference.child("posts");
    // I can not have multiple equal : Query AllPostsQuery = databaseReference.child("posts").orderByChild("type").equalTo(5);
    return AllPostsQuery;
}
```

then
the adapter

```
    @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Set up Layout Manager, reverse layout
    mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    mManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mManager);

    // Set up FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with the Query
    Query postsQuery = getQuery(mDatabase);
    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(Post.class, R.layout.item_post,
            PostViewHolder.class, postsQuery) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, final Post model, final int position) {
            final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);
            if ((model.type!=1)&& (model.type!=2) && (model.type!=6)) viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                else viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Set click listener for the whole post view
            final String postKey = postRef.getKey();
            viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Launch PostDetailActivity   ....   ....
            });


        }
    };
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

The setVisibility works but there are still empty space displayed by the adapter for other unwanted records

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035700/2809351

Comment: You want `View.GONE`, which removes the item from the view hierarchy (instead of just hiding its contents). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223413/how-to-hide-an-item-from-recycler-view-on-a-particular-condition

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question, you might be able to reduce the data download by using a range query: `AllPostsQuery.orderByChild("type").startAt(1).endAt(6)`. You'll still need to filter in the code, but it may transfer less data.